# Swift Functional Programming

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I have an `String` array:

```
let animals = ["Cat", "Chicken", "Fish", "Dog", "Mouse", "Pig", "Monkey"]
```

I want to get the result like this:

```
[(C, ["Cat", "Chicken"]),
 (D, ["Dog"]),
 (F, ["Fish"]),
 (M, ["Mouse", "Monkey"]),
 (P, ["Pig"])]
```

I have tried:

```
let animals = ["Cat", "Chicken", "Fish", "Dog", "Mouse", "Pig", "Monkey"]
typealias Entry = (Character, [String])

func buildIndex(words: [String]) -> [Entry] {
    let distinctLetters = Array(Set(words.map { Character($0.substringToIndex($0.startIndex.advancedBy(1))) })).sort()
    return distinctLetters.map({ (letter) -> Entry in
        return (letter, words.filter({ (word) -> Bool in
            Character(word.substringToIndex(word.startIndex.advancedBy(1))) == letter
        }))
    })
}
print(buildIndex(animals))

//[("C", ["Cat", "Chicken"]), ("D", ["Dog"]), ("F", ["Fish"]), ("M", ["Mouse", "Monkey"]), ("P", ["Pig"])]
```

Now I want to use it with `$` syntax.

I have tried:

```
func buildIndex(words: [String]) -> [Entry] {
    let distinctLetters = Array(Set(words.map { Character($0.substringToIndex($0.startIndex.advancedBy(1))) })).sort()
    return distinctLetters.map{ ($0, words.filter {
        Character($0.substringToIndex($0.startIndex.advancedBy(1))) == $0 // I want to get $0 from the map, not from the filter
    })}  
}
```

[image]

But it says:

> overloads for '==' exist with these partially matching parameter
>   lists: (Character, Character), (String, String)
>           Character($0.substringToIndex($0.startIndex.advancedBy(1))) == $0

I have also tried:

```
func buildIndex(words: [String]) -> [Entry] {
    let distinctLetters = Array(Set(words.map { Character($0.substringToIndex($0.startIndex.advancedBy(1))) })).sort()
    return distinctLetters.map { ($0, words.filter { distinctLetters.contains(Character($0.substringToIndex($0.startIndex.advancedBy(1)))) })}
}
```

But It doesn't work well. It prints:

```
[("C", ["Cat", "Chicken", "Fish", "Dog", "Mouse", "Pig", "Monkey"]), ("D", ["Cat", "Chicken", "Fish", "Dog", "Mouse", "Pig", "Monkey"]), ("F", ["Cat", "Chicken", "Fish", "Dog", "Mouse", "Pig", "Monkey"]), ("M", ["Cat", "Chicken", "Fish", "Dog", "Mouse", "Pig", "Monkey"]), ("P", ["Cat", "Chicken", "Fish", "Dog", "Mouse", "Pig", "Monkey"])]
```

So how to achieve this with `$` systax.

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have a collision between different `$0`. Just keep your parameters named, it makes them more readable. By replacing names by `$0` you are doing one thing only with your code - you are decreasing readability. You are not making the code more or less functional.

Comment: Your second try of `buildIndex` looks like it has some copy/paste errors.

Comment: Because the compiler din't know `$0` from `map`. When I type `$0`, the compiler hint 2 $0, one is `String` and the other is `Character`. Surely I chose `Character`, but It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
let animals = ["Cat", "Chicken", "Fish", "Dog", "Mouse", "Pig", "Monkey"]

let catalog = Array(Set(animals.map( {(ch) -> Character in ch.characters.first! })))
    .sort()
    .map({ (ch) -> (Character, [String]) in
        (ch, animals.filter { (name) -> Bool in name.hasPrefix(String(ch)) })
    })

print(catalog)
//[("C", ["Cat", "Chicken"]), ("D", ["Dog"]), ("F", ["Fish"]), ("M", ["Mouse", "Monkey"]), ("P", ["Pig"])]
```

Comment: Switching to Character is a good idea, but the question is "Can I use dot notation to solve this?"

Answer (score 1):

What about doing it this way:

```
func buildIndex2(words: [String]) -> [Entry] {
    var res = [Character:[String]]()
    words.map({ res[$0[0]] = (res[$0[0]] ?? []) + [$0] })
    return res.sort{ $0.0 < $1.0 }
}
```

or even more $-way (in my opinion, less readable, though):

```
func buildIndex3(words: [String]) -> [Entry] {
    return animals.reduce([Character:[String]]()) {
        var res = $0
        res[$1[0]] = ($0[$1[0]] ?? []) + [$1]
        return res
    }.sort{ $0.0 < $1.0 }
}
```

String extension:

```
extension String {
    subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
        return self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]
    }
}
```

The advantage in this solution is that you don't have to run filter for every letter you get in each step of the last map.

Comment: Added one more solution for getting rid of the scope variable `res`, but it's less readable in my opinion...

Comment: Yes. A lot of `$0` here, the reason I asked this question because of the picture above.

Comment: Well, the problem in your picture is that you have a scope within a scope. In my case, there is no $-collision.

Comment: If you're not using the result of `map` (in your first example), then you should just use `forEach` instead. Also your last `map` is completely redundant in both examples, as `sort` already returns a `[(Character, [String])]` – you can freely cast it to a `[Entry]`.

Comment: @originaluser2 Nice observation! Thanks for the correction, working it in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use functional programming, you should focus on what to do but not how to do, and it also should be declarative. My solution is just for inspiration.

https://github.com/unchartedworks/HaskellSwift

```
import HaskellSwift

func test() {
    let animals                                   = ["Cat", "Chicken", "Fish", "Dog", "Mouse", "Pig", "Monkey"]
    let hasFirstLetter: (String, String) -> Bool  = { $0.first == $1.first }
    let pair: ([String]) -> (Character, [String]) = { ($0.first?.first ?? Character(""), $0)}
    let categorize                                = map(pair) .. curry(groupBy)(hasFirstLetter) .. sort
    let results                                   = categorize(animals)
    print(results)
}
```